# Query works in mysql but not in PHP

Tags: php

Following is my prepared statement which I am using to make insertion in a table. When I run the same query in mysql by only changing `?` in actual values then the query runs successfully but it doesnot in PHP and gives following error:

`Call to a member function execute() on a non-object`

Kindly let me know what I did wrong:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("
    INSERT INTO test_given (
        test_id, test_giver, test_completed, dt_created
    )
    SELECT * FROM (
         SELECT ?, ?, '0',NOW()
    ) AS tmp
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT test_id FROM test_given WHERE test_id  = ? AND test_giver  = ?
    ) limit 1
");

// s means only string input is allowed 
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $qid, $username,$qid, $username);
```

*Note: I echoed $qid, $username and they are getting right values.*

Comment: You __can't__ use bind variables for table or column names, but you're trying to use them for the column names in your SELECT

Comment: I'm no DBA but my god that's a long query.  I've gotta catch my breath after reading that thing.

Comment: @Deryck actually the query is in one line so it looks bigger to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `?` for table names. In SQL, values look like `"value"`, while table/column names look like ``colname`` (backtick, not single quote); they're not interchangeable.

You can use `sprintf` and manually escape the table name with `mysqli_escape_string`, ie.:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare(sprintf("
    INSERT INTO test_given (
        test_id, test_giver, test_completed, dt_created
    )
    SELECT * FROM (
         SELECT `%s`, `%s`, '0',NOW()
    ) AS tmp
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT test_id FROM test_given WHERE test_id  = ? AND test_giver  = ?
    ) limit 1
"), $qid, $username);

// s means only string input is allowed 
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $qid, $username);
```